# MySQL CASE and RPAD issue

Tags: mysql

I have this query below which is working perfectly. I just can't figure out how to use the RPAD function on val_4. I tried using RPAD within the CASE, but it fails.

```
SELECT RPAD(val_1,1,' '), RPAD(val_2,9,' '), RPAD(val_3,6,' '),
    (CASE val_4
        WHEN 'abc' THEN 'USEABLE'
        WHEN 'abcd' THEN 'USEABLE'
        WHEN 'abcde' THEN 'USEABLE'
        ELSE 'UNUSABLE'
    END)
FROM lists
INTO OUTFILE '/path/to/file'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ''
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity what is the point of using `RPAD` in that particular case since you always have constant literal values out of your `CASE`? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @peterm I'm guessing it's just an abstraction.

Comment: Yes, the Value is not always USEABLE and the system it is going into needs to have the field a certain width.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrapping the whole case:

```
SELECT RPAD(val_1,1,' '), RPAD(val_2,9,' '), RPAD(val_3,6,' '),
    RPAD(CASE val_4
        WHEN 'abc' THEN 'USEABLE'
        WHEN 'abcd' THEN 'USEABLE'
        WHEN 'abcde' THEN 'USABLE'
        ELSE 'abcdef'
    END, 6, ' ')
FROM lists
INTO OUTFILE '/path/to/file'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ''
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

[SQL Fiddle example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f4b6b/1)

---

Or, wrapping just the value of `val_4`:

```
SELECT RPAD(val_1,1,' '), RPAD(val_2,9,' '), RPAD(val_3,6,' '),
    CASE RPAD(val_4,4,' ')
        WHEN 'abc' THEN 'USEABLE'
        WHEN 'abcd' THEN 'USEABLE'
        WHEN 'abcde' THEN 'USABLE'
        ELSE 'abcdef'
    END
FROM lists
INTO OUTFILE '/path/to/file'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ''
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

[SQL Fiddle example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f4b6b/3)